# Saving a non-animated version of animated beamer/fancyslides slides

Tags: beamer, pdf, overlays, animations

I'm new to LaTeX so I don't even know how to phrase my question to search for it!

I am making lecture slides for a course. I use `\pause` before pretty much every bullet point so we can go over each point one by one. However, this makes each bullet point into a new slide, so a 20 frame presentation quickly becomes a 50+ slide PDF document. For the purposes of posting the lecture slides on the course website so students can study them later, I would like a version of the PDF which only has the frames (ie all the bulletpoints, no frames that are blank or just have the first few bullets). I could do this by removing/commenting out all the `\pause` and creating a second document, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Related: is there a way to put slide numbers (by frame, not by bullet point) on fancyslides? This:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

doesn't work.

---

Here's an example of my document (which uses [fancyslides.cls](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~p_lup/?page_id=1057)):

```
\documentclass[handout]{fancyslides}
\usetheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=\yourowntexcol} 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=\yourowntexcol} 
\newcommand{\structureopacity}{0.80} 
\newcommand{\strcolor}{blue} 
\newcommand{\yourowntexcol}{white} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\color{blue}\huge Slide title}
\itemized{
\pause
\item bullet points 
\pause
\item shown one by one
\pause
\item one frame, four slides
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`[handout]` doesn't seem to do anything on fancyslides. I suspect my footer page number issue has to do with the fact that my font color and background color are white?

Comment: `handout` doesn't work because you're using `fancyslides` class which is based on `beamer` class but doesn't have all its features.

Comment: Okay, that's what I suspected, thanks. Perhaps it's just easier to find/replace all the `\pause` with `%\pause`.

Any suggestions on getting a slide count or other progress bar?

Comment: Forget my previous comment. `facyslides.cls` is declared without options and only uses `LoadClass{beamer}` without any option. Therefore when `\documentclass[handout]{fancyslides}` is written nothing happens with `handout`. If you change `LoadClass{beamer}` to `LoadClass[handout]{beamer}` inside `fancyslides.cls` you'll get a `handout` document. Although I recommend to rephrase your question (or make a new one) because I'm sure there exist better solutions. For the page numbers add `\useoutertheme{infolines}` as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing `fancyslides.cls`, your main document should start like this:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\documentclass{fancyslides}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

[**tricky part stolen from [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178504/36296)'s answer, so please accept his**]

You could use the `handout` option of the beamer class. But as [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178504/36296) showed in his answer, this only works with a trick:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\documentclass{fancyslides}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item A.\pause
            \item B.
        \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing seemed to change? I'm using fancyslides if it makes any difference.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your code. Like this it will be much easier to help you

Comment: Okay, edited. Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

`fancyslides.cls` starts with

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{fancyslides}[2013/04/23 my custom beamer slides class]
\LoadClass{beamer}
```

This means that `fancyslides` doesn't have any declared option and that in case any `beamer` option is declared (`\documentclass[handout]{fancyslides}`), the option won't be passed to `beamer`.

A possible solution could be change third in `fancyslides.cls` line to `\LoadClassWithOptions{beamer}`. This way all `beamer` options declared in your `.tex` file will be applied to `beamer.cls`.

---

If you need page numbers add `\useoutertheme{infolines}` (or any other theme which shows frame numbers) to your preamble.